# XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/core

Tags: angular, angular-material, visual-studio-code

I am Trying to use Angular Material in my angular app but getting error When i Write NGModule In My typescript file

My Ts File[image]

Error i am Getting
[image]

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@NgModule` came with Angular2 rc.5 you need upgrade your library and re-architect your structure.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc5-2016-08-09

Comment: Thanks ill take a look